# How can I export georeference bodies and planes to ..obj maintaining all CRS georeferenced coordinate data

Tags: export, obj

Using blender 2.83. Generated model with BlenderGis. Exporting planes and bodies only. Export to .obj files. Importing the .obj files back to blender 2.83 works but importing into other GIS does only preserve local x,y,z coordinates and not the georeference coordinates.

Comment: Hi welcome to the site! This is an excellent question for this site, but I just want to mention if you don't get many answers here there may be more people knowledgeable about GIS things on [https://gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will submit it to the suggested site.   Best wishes